# Do TTF font files need to be placed in Fonts folder?

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-installer, installshield, truetype

If an application depends on a certain `.TTF` font file, can this file be placed in the application folder, or does it need to be put in the `Windows Fonts` folder?

Can installers like `Installshield` install font files into the `Windows Fonts` folder properly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see [Microsoft recommends](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960) to install them in Windows Fonts folder.

Most [professional setup authoring tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools) can register font so you will have no problems doing this with Installshield.